# is possible to Turn on GPS from background service not activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, service, gps

I'm creating an app to track user coordinates. i get a problem when gps is off. 
so that's what I want to ask. is it possible to turn on gps from background service android. like every 30min once, make service turn on gps and get location.

Comment: use alarm manager along with intent service

Answer (score 1):

Service will not run for long time. There are restriction on background services. You can use Alarm manager for your functionality.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: so is it possible to turn on gps without user action ?

Comment: No you have to ask user to start gps.

Comment: @Chielarck Depends on what you mean by turn on.  If they have GPS disabed entirely, you can't change that.  But if they have GPS enabled, but not actively looking for a location, you can turn it on by just requesting a GPS location.

Comment: Root required. 
Code samples may be obtained from https://github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler3/